# Iterate through path type inside 'WHERE' statement

Tags: postgresql, coordinates, loop, for-loop

I have a table defined as following

```
CREATE TABLE public.geometry_polyline_volume (
    id          serial not null primary key,
    distance    float not null,
    height      float not null,
    coordinates path not null );
```

Is there any way to iterate the *coordinates* in order to filter some specific points inside the *coordinates* ?
Somthing like this ->

```
SELECT * FROM public.geometry_polyline_volume WHERE FOR coord in coordinates DO coord[0] > 15 END;
```

Comment: If you want to manipulate the geometries, it is best to use the PostGIS extension and its `geometry` type instead of the native geometric types.

Comment: your query would then be `select * from mytable where st_Xmax(geom) > 15;`

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution with PostGIS extension installed, the following query should be working :

```sql
WITH condition AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    ST_X((ST_DumpPoints(CAST(path AS geometry))).geom) > 15 AS value
  FROM
    public.geometry_polyline_volume
),

filter AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT id
  FROM condition
  WHERE value IS TRUE
)

SELECT gpv.*
FROM
  public.geometry_polyline_volume gpv
  INNER JOIN filter ON gpv.id = filter.id
;
```

Explanations :

- `condition` CTE extract table ids where the X coordinate is superior to 15
- `filter` CTE keeps only distinct ids where the condition is true
- The final query filter the table `geometry_polyline_volume` with an inner join to `filter` filtered ids.

---

**EDIT**

A more simple and elegant solution by @JGH :

```sql
SELECT gpv.*
FROM public.geometry_polyline_volume gpv
WHERE ST_XMax(CAST(path AS geometry) > 15
;
```

Comment: can't `st_xMax(cast..)` be used directly in the where clause on the main table?

Comment: Yes, indeed, I added the solution.